# IOS Push Notification using c#

Tags: c#, apple-push-notifications

I want to send Json string from  c# in following format for IOS Push notification :

```
{
    "pushType": "Notification",
    "notifications": [
        {
            "notificationId": 1,
            "notificationTitle": "Notification 1",
            "notificationText": "You are reading your notification 1",
            "notificationExpiryDate": "yyyy-MM-dd"
        },
        {
            "notificationId": 2,
            "notificationTitle": "Notification 2",
            "notificationText": "You are reading your notification 2",
            "notificationExpiryDate": "yyyy-MM-dd"
        },
        {
            "notificationId": 3,
            "notificationTitle": "Notification 3",
            "notificationText": "You are reading your notification 3",
            "notificationExpiryDate": "yyyy-MM-dd"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to send simple message but am not able to send array of string.
Please help me out for this as am struggling from last two days.

Comment: Please show the code that you have used to send the notifications and mention any libraries you are using.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using JavascriptSerializer. Here is a code sample using anonymous code declaration

```
var obj = new
        {
            pushType = "Notification",
            notification = new[]{
                new {
                notificationId = 1,
                notificationTitle = "Notification 1",
                notificationText = "You are reading your notification 1",
                notificationExpiryDate = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                },
                new {
                notificationId = 2,
                notificationTitle = "Notification 2",
                notificationText = "You are reading your notification 2",
                notificationExpiryDate = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                },
                new {
                notificationId = 3,
                notificationTitle = "Notification 3",
                notificationText = "You are reading your notification 3",
                notificationExpiryDate = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                }
            }
        };            

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string outputstring = serializer.Serialize(obj);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for reply but am using .net .40 and javascriptserializer is not available in this version ..is there any other way

Comment: Hello,
you can use Javascript Serializer in .NET v4.0. You just need to add the System.Web.Extensions reference. Then simply add "using System.Web.Script.Serialization;" in the beginning of your code.